# how to disable button in kendo grid column

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, angularjs-ng-disabled

I need to have 2 buttons in a cell. One is calling some function, other is disabling previous button that calls some function. I tried this(part of my template in a column):

```
return '<button kendo-button class="validate" ng-click="MyFunction($event)">' + txt.TXT_SEND_TO_SAP + '</button>' + '&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
'<button kendo-button ng-click="Disable($event)">disable</button>' + '&nbsp;&nbsp;'
```

and this function that calls disabling:

```
      $scope.Disable = function (e) {
      var data = $scope.grid.dataSource.view();
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          $(data[i]).prev().prop("disabled", true)
      }
  }
```

what I do wrong? Thanks

Comment: Try using the button object enable() method: http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/api/javascript/ui/button#methods-enable

Comment: unfortunately doesn't help, tried it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event parameter (e) gives you the clicked button, `e.target`. From that you can get the button to disable via `.prev(".validate")` and then use the KendoUI widget to disable it:

```
$scope.Disable = function (e) {
  var btn = $(e.target);
  var toDisable = btn.prev(".validate").data("kendoButton");
  toDisable.enable(false);
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/ULIdA)**